# Class not running - getting no results

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I am new to python classes and I am trying to run this code but I don't get any results:

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, mascalzone, it_fusion):
        self.mascalzone = mascalzone
        self.it_fusion = it_fusion

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"this restaurant is Italian and is named: {self.mascalzone}")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"the restaurant {self.it_fusion} is open , please come in!")

        # make  instance below:
        restaurant = Restaurant('open', 9)

        # printing two attributes individually:
        print(f"this:{restaurant.it_fusion}")
        print(f"that:{restaurant.mascalzone}")

        # calling both methods:
        restaurant.describe_restaurant()
        restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

Comment: Indentation matters...

Comment: This code does nothing other than **defining** a class. You have to create an instance of it and call the methods in order to run the code.

Comment: @KalusD. the functions are called but they are indented into the second function

Comment: I believe if you were to call the `open_restaurant` method you would get a `RecursionError` because as written right now it will just continuously spawn new restaurants and then call _their_ `open_restaurant` method.  You probably want a classmethod, staticmethod, or function outside the class to actually contain your build restaurant helper

Comment: Everything starting from `# make instance below` needs to be at the left margin.

Comment: I guess Uri messed up the indentation when creating the question. Hint: Paste the code in, marked it and press the `{}` button.

Comment: @lemonhead: You were being confused about what's going on because the indentation was messed-up initially — see updated version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how classes work. Your first part of code should be *describing* the class, and then the second be actually *creating* an instance of the class. So either you thought that you had to define classes inside of the definition, or you forgot to indent well.

in `open_restaurant()`, remove creating an instance of `Restaurant` and place it outside of the class definition. Then put the code calling both methods also outside of the code. The rest of your code is fine.

The code:

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, mascalzone, it_fusion):
        self.mascalzone = mascalzone
        self.it_fusion = it_fusion

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"this restaurant is Italian and is named: {self.mascalzone}")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"the restaurant {self.it_fusion} is open , please come in!")

restaurant = Restaurant('open', 9)
restaurant.open_restaurant()
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
```